# how can i get a specific line of command promt output in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows, cmd

I need to get a specific line of command prompt line output and save it in a string variable in vb.net.

Please tell me how to get the line output form command prompt to vb.net and also how to get a specific line.

Comment: You mean capture the output from a process?

Comment: yes and also I need to get a specific line from it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will need to start the process and then capture the Standard Output. The below code will help you.

```
   Dim process As New Process()
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("YourApplication.exe", "arguments")
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    process.StartInfo = startInfo
    process.Start()

    Dim output As String
    Using streamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = process.StandardOutput
        output = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
```

Once done, you will need to create a file with `output` content and read the specific line from it